# I need help with this step in solving a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$dx=t{ {lnp-1}\over{ln^2p}}dp+{{p}\over{lnp}}dt$$ comes to:
$$0=t{ {lnp-1}\over{ln^2p}}dp+({{p}\over{lnp}}-p)dt$$ how is this possible , i know i'm missing something trivial.. i know its a short question.. will be deteled as soon as answer but this is important to me as im on a timeline.. Now i must type in order for it to meet standards, ie be published, so the following text is of no important but as to entertain if one's humor entices so..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The differential on the right is exact.  It is equal to

$$d (\frac{pt}{\ln(p)})$$

Comment: i dont understand how the second expression i wrote is concluded, any help?

Comment: Im aware what you wrote as this was the begining question

Comment: I was referring to the first expression.

Comment: Do you know how to get from the first expression to the second is the question.

Comment: Oh ok.  That was not clear.  It looks like you need to know more about the variables in question here.  Without more, the second equation does not follow from the first.

Comment: ok, x=tp/lnp for one. and x'=p

Comment: im laughing now as i wrote this

Comment: ill give you the points for participating